# Open subreport depending on column value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have 6 possible subreports and 6 possible values in one column. I want to click on that column and open the subreport associated with that value.
I found a couple places recommending this

```
=IIf(Fields!DataType.Value = "XXX","<PATH>",
IIf(Fields!DataType.Value = "YYY","<PATH>",NOTHING)
```

With this format, It won't do anything, No clicking option on the column

My path is on a server so it's something like /homefolder/reports/subreports/report
This returns item containing invalid char and doesn't show the report

This is the expression I have now that does not work. it returns databox is invalid error.

```
IIf(Fields!DataType.Value = "PLE",/Reports/Subreports/PLEReport,NOTHING)
```

Comment: I got it to work if I add another link where I put NOTHING but it only goes to that report regardless of if the first expresison is true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the Column Field>**Text Box Properties**

[image]

Comment: That's what I did but when I put my path in quotes, I get an error saying I have invalid character in my path because of the \, without the quotes I can't click on the column

Comment: are you putting the complete URL link with http, like "http://urlname/reports/report1.rdl" ?

Comment: I found the problem, There where some blank spaces inserted in the textbox value at some point, I added a trim and everything works.